# Oracle SQL Left Join with sum and fields other than "join on" fields

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have two tables.

First table is "a" with fields a.pr, a.info and a.id.  Second table is "b" with fields b.id and b.amount.

a.id = b.id, though multiple b.id's may match with a single a.id.

My SQL statement is as follows:

```
SELECT a.pr, a.info, a.id, SUM(b.amount) AS total
FROM   a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
WHERE  a.pr = "549"
GROUP BY a.id
```

Now, this doesn't work.  It throws a "not a GROUP BY expression" error.  As I understand it, I need a subquery, but none of the examples I found seemed to exactly match what I am trying to accomplish here, and I couldn't get any of them to work right.

What would the full SQL statement (with subquery) look like in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You should group by all the fields in your select clause:

```
SELECT a.pr, a.info, a.id, SUM(b.amount) AS total
FROM   a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
WHERE  a.pr = "549"
GROUP BY a.pr, a.info, a.id
```

See [ORA-00979](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00979_not_a_group_by_expression.htm).

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan pointed out all columns that do not have an aggregate function need to be part of group by clause

This link provides a good explanation 
[But *WHY* Must That Column Be Contained in an Aggregate Function or the GROUP BY clause?](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx)